# How to "toggle" between IText objects (paragraphs of text) on selection with fabricjs canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I want to be able to select from a dropdown to "toggle" between styled IText paragraphs onto my fabricjs canvas but am having trouble making it happen. I tried borrowing from this, which was to do similarly with images, with no luck:

```
//oImgObj bread and butter, kudos @grunt
function replaceImage(oImgObj, imgUrl) {
  if (!isImageLoaded) return; //return if initial image not loaded
  var imgElem = oImgObj._element; //reference to actual image element
  imgElem.src = imgUrl; //set image source
  imgElem.onload = () => canvas.renderAll(); //render on image load
}
```

How might I accomplish this with editable blocks of text?

Comment: you want text from textarea to IText object?

Comment: I'd like to designate some blocks of text that appear on the canvas with a click, and replace any existing ones

Answer (score 1):

You can set your text to a text object with the attribute `text`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text = new fabric.IText('FabricJs is Awsome',{
  left:50,top:50
});
canvas.add(text);
function replace(option){
 var val = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
 text.set('text',val);
 canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
 border: blue dotted 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<br>
<textarea></textarea><button onclick='replace()'>Replace</button>
```

Comment: This is great but how might I go about having buttons replace the current text with new blocks of text, instead of having to type them? In other words, say you had 2 buttons and one inserts one chunk of text but clicking the second button would replace it with a different chunk of text (and vice versa)?

Comment: From where you will get that blocks of text?

Comment: Hey Durga this might help explain what I'm looking for better. [In this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s42orj2e/3/) I have two text functions; I'd only like one to be displayed at a time. In other words, if you click Two, One should disappear and be replaced by Two's function and if you press One again One would replace Two.